# Why is eslint giving this parse error in .eslintrc.js

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I'm getting this strange error when trying to run `eslint ./src --cache --fix`. In my project:

```
0:0  error  Parsing error: '{' expected
```

This is the contents of `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect'
    }
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'prettier'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition': 'warn'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json', './.eslintrc.js']
  }
}
```

It's almost as if `eslint` is expecting a json file but this is the file for a while so I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Try to remove './.eslintrc.js' from parserOptions